# genetic algorithm with different categories of parameters

Tags: algorithms, genetic-algorithms

I am trying to use a genetic algorithm to solve a problem. However, I find it difficult to represent the chromosomes in my problem. In the problem, I have two categories of parameters, and each gene inside the chromosome has a specific range of values.

For example, Category $A$ has chromosome $X$ that has the following genes:
$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$, where

$x_1$ takes value between $1$ and $5$ (inclusive).

$x_2$ takes value between $10$ and $30$ (inclusive).

$x_3$ takes value in the set $\{1,4,6,10\}$.

Also, Category $B$ has chromosome $Y$ that have genes with different values.

The difficulty here is how can I encode the chromosomes $X$ and $Y$ with the different ranges of values?